# Facebook demo app fails to build on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

iOS beginner here. I'm trying to build the [Facebook Demo App](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/DemoApp) but I keep getting the following error:

```
Check dependencies

[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv6).
```

Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason it seems that your project doesn't have an architecture set. Click on the project name, then on Build Settings, and select the architectures as shown below:

[image: Xcode 4 Architecture Settings]

***Edited to add***

Also ensure the "Valid Architectures" include all three architectures:

[image: Xcode 4 Valid Architecture Settings]

Comment: i just checked and i have the same exact setup but it's not working.

Comment: @John I edited my answer to show the other key architecture settings that may be set incorrectly.